# How to scale a 3D object on 2 dimensions only?

Tags: autocad

How can I scale a 3D object only on 2 dimensions with Autocad?

For instance, I would like to scale a complex object whose maximum dimensions are 50x30x10 (on axes `x`, `y` and `z`, respectively) obtaining an object whose maximum dimensions are 75x45x10, i.e. I would like to scale it up to 150% on `x` and `y` axes only, leaving unchanged the `z` dimension.

Answer (score 1):

This method, directly pasted from [Autodesk Knowledge Network](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-E96829D6-A58A-48B6-8B65-A7C99C879262-htm.html) would appear to be the solution you seek. Using a plane for the two dimensions you wish to scale should exclude the third from the changes.

Use this method to resize the objects only along a plane that you specify.

```
Click Home tab Modify3D Scale.
```

Select the objects and subobjects you want to scale using the following methods:

```
Press and hold Ctrl to select subobjects (faces, edges, and vertices).
Release Ctrl to select entire objects.
```

When you have selected all objects, press Enter.

The Scale gizmo is displayed at the center of the selected object or objects.
Do one of the following:

```
To scale along a plane: Hover the cursor over one of the bars found between each of the axes of the gizmo until it turns yellow. Click the yellow bar.
To scale uniformly: Hover the cursor over the triangular area closest to the center point of the gizmo until it turns yellow. Click the yellow area.
To scale along an axis: Hover the cursor over one of the axes of the gizmo until it turns yellow. Click the yellow axis.
```

[image: axis display]

To resize the selection, drag and release, or enter a scale factor while holding the mouse button.